# One mysqli table into JSON format with PHP

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, json, mysqli

I am trying to get the desired return I want with a specific mysqli table, which has the following structure:

```
id | name  | parentid
--------------------
1  | Boss    | 0
2  | Bob     | 1
3  | Chef1   | 1
4  | Chef2   | 1
5  | Lara    | 3
6  | Kim     | 4
7  | Nick    | 1
63 | Oldboss | 20
```

I need to get for each parent name a new:

```
[
  {  
    "name": "Boss",
    "attributes": {
      "data-id": "1"
    },
    "children": [
      {      
        "name": "Bob",
        "attributes": {
          "data-id": "2"
        }
      },
      {
        "name": "Chef1",
        "attributes": {
          "data-id": "3"
        }
      },
      {
        "name": "Chef2",
        "attributes": {
          "data-id": "4"
        }
      },
      {
        "name": "Nick",
        "attributes": {
          "data-id": "7"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  {  
    "name": "Chef1",
    "attributes": {
      "data-id": "3"
    },
    "children": [
      {      
        "name": "Lara",
        "attributes": {
          "data-id": "5"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  {  
    "name": "Chef2",
    "attributes": {
      "data-id": "4"
    },
    "children": [
      {      
        "name": "Kim",
        "attributes": {
          "data-id": "6"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

That's what I need to get, for each Name which has childs need to get at the top, but also displayed under his parent. This will create the same result when using an echo into a while format. But I just can't get the array / JSON to build up how I want it to result. This is what I have currently:

```
$returnarray = array();

$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT
  t_names.name AS Name2,
  t_names.id AS ID2
FROM t_names
  INNER JOIN t_names t_names_1
    ON t_names.id = t_names_1.parentid
WHERE t_names.parentid <> 63
AND t_names.id <> 63";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){


$subarray = array(
        "data-id"=> $row['ID2']
    );  

$headarray = array(
    "name"=> $row2['Name2'],
    "attributes"=> $subarray,
    "children"=>$rowarray2
);

$sql2 = "SELECT DISTINCT id, name, parentid FROM t_names WHERE parentid = '{$row[ID2]}' ";
$result2 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql2);
while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2)){

$subarray2 = array(
        "data-id"=> $row2['id']
    ); 

$rowarray = array(
        "name"=> $row2['Name'],
        "attributes"=> $subarray2
    );  

$rowarray2[] = $rowarray;

}

$returnarray[] = $headarray;

}

echo "<pre>";

echo json_encode($returnarray, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);

echo "</pre>";
```

Above result does create a json format that results in the code:

```
- Boss
Bob
Chef1
Chef2
Nick

-Chef1
Bob
Chef1
Chef2
Nick
Lara

-Chef2
Bob
Chef1
Chef2
Nick
Lara
Kim
```

So it creates the groups, but it keeps using the data from previous groups and adds the correct names after them.

What am I dong wrong with my arrays?

Comment: isn't `$row[ID2]` referring to ID2 as a constant? Its there in your sql query.

Comment: @Xor actually the quotes are optional around the array index only when the variable itself is wrapped in double quotes.

Comment: @jeff  But if wrapped in single quote it isn't a variable at all, just a literal. That raises the question what if you want it to work with a constant, :). Either way I think it is a bad practice, pollutes code and what not. I'd rather concat or sprintf it.

Comment: @Xorifelse if wrapped in a single quote, then variable interpolation will not work at all. It's fine to not use it. PHP is flexible. I think one should just pick a coding style and be consistent.

Comment: @jeff Hmmz, correct. In a literal string, interpolation does not occur (rather avoid expensive words) . And consistency yes, but defining an array with quotes and using it without is an inconsistency by itself. And it seems I was spot on, just tested the code and it throws a notice of the use of a undefined constant, but assumes it as an array key. So this could potentially break the code. In other words, it works but `{$row['ID2']}` is the way it should be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just join the table once on that unary relation, iterate through the rows grouping under the same parent indices, and then collapse top-tier.

```
function transformEmployee($user)
{
    $output['name'] = $user['employee'];
    $output['attributes']['data-id'] = $user['emp_id'];
    return $output;
}

$mysqli = new mysqli('server', 'username', 'password', 'database');

$sql = '
    SELECT bosses.id AS boss_id, bosses.name AS boss,
        employees.id AS emp_id, employees.name AS employee
    FROM names bosses
    JOIN names employees
      ON bosses.id = employees.parent_id
';

$names = $mysqli->query($sql)->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

foreach ($names as $name) {
    $result[$name['boss_id']]['name'] = $name['boss'];
    $result[$name['boss_id']]['attributes']['data-id'] = $name['boss_id'];
    $result[$name['boss_id']]['children'] []= transformEmployee($name);
}

echo json_encode(array_values($result), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Comment: SIR, you are briljant! This gives me exact the result i needed with a fast result.